# For user verification, you do need to store data on server side even when using JWT correct?

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, jwt

While I understand how jwt works for authentication, I'm trying to build registration.

Registration has a step that requires verification.

1. User enters the phone number
2. Code is sent via sms to user
3. User enters the code and device is verified

Since it's an API for mobile app there is no session/cookie built in.

I'm wondering if I can not implement cookie like system for mobile. And just make it work with JWT. But I don't have much experience with this.

This is my current flow:

1. User makes a POST request with Phone #
2. I respond with JWT (Time:Number)
3. I also send code via SMS
4. User sends the code via POST and JWT

Problem:

1. I don't know if code belongs to user or not, as I didn't save the code in DB.
2. I can't put into payload as it's just encoded not encrypted. (why is it not encrypted, what's the point of sending plain payload, what's even the point of JWT & didn't signed cookies already do that? they had session string encrypted so you couldn't change session string without invalidating the cookie)

Answer (score 0):

JWT is overcome authentication/authorization mostly in APIs. JWT Access Token/[Refresh Token](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) is nothing but a JSON data in an encrypted form. JWTs can be signed using a secret (with the HMAC algorithm) or a public/private key pair using RSA or ECDSA. Key pair using RSA or ECDSA is more preferable as a security point of view. You can check authentication/authorization by decryption JWTs.

JWT token itself contains expiry date, so you can just configure expiration time to it. Access tokens are to check that user is authorized or not. Refresh tokens is necessary to get a new access token, generally used when the old access tokens are expired. Refresh token and Access token both expire but refresh token is long-lived compare to access tokens.

Generally developers use access token only but it is preferable to use access and refresh token both.